# Checkbox values are not updating when state is set: ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I am having an app with two sections. Left section contains the categories and the right section containing the items under it. Under each category, I have the button to select all or unselect all items. I see the state changes happening in the code ( it is pretty printed inside HTML) but the checkbox values are not getting updated. Can someone help?

https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-carson-dy46k8?file=/src/App.js

```
export const RightSection = ({ name, apps, json, setJson }) => {
  function handleSelectAll(categoryName, type) {
    const checked = type === "Select All" ? true : false;
    const updated = Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(json).map(([key, category]) => {
        if (category.name !== categoryName) {
          return [key, category];
        }
        const { name, tiles, ...rest } = category;
        return [
          key,
          {
            name,
            ...rest,
            tiles: tiles.map((item) => ({
              ...item,
              checked
            }))
          }
        ];
      })
    );
    setJson(updated);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <input
          type="button"
          value={`select all under ${name}`}
          onClick={() => handleSelectAll(name, "Select All")}
        />
        <input
          type="button"
          value={`unselect all under ${name}`}
          onClick={() => handleSelectAll(name, "Unselect All")}
        />
        <h4 style={{ color: "blue" }}>{name} Items</h4>
        {apps.map((app) => {
          return (
            <section key={app.tileName}>
              <input checked={app.checked} type="checkbox" />
              <span key={app.tileName}>{app.tileName}</span> <br />
            </section>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

```
import { useEffect, useState, useMemo } from "react";
import { SidebarItem } from "./SideBarItem";
import { RightSection } from "./RightSection";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const dummyJson = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      cat1: {
        id: "cat1",
        name: "Category 1",
        tiles: [
          {
            tileName: "abc",
            searchable: true,
            checked: false
          },
          {
            tileName: "def",
            searchable: true,
            checked: true
          }
        ]
      },
      cat2: {
        id: "cat2",
        name: "Category 2",
        tiles: [
          {
            tileName: "ab",
            searchable: true,
            checked: true
          },
          {
            tileName: "xyz",
            searchable: true,
            checked: false
          }
        ]
      },
      cat3: {
        id: "cat3",
        name: "Category 3",
        tiles: [
          {
            tileName: "lmn",
            searchable: true,
            checked: true
          },
          {
            tileName: "",
            searchable: false,
            checked: false
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  }, []);

  const [json, setJson] = useState(dummyJson);
  const [active, setActive] = useState(dummyJson["cat1"]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <div>
          <ul>
            {Object.values(json).map((details) => {
              const { id, name } = details;
              return (
                <SidebarItem
                  key={name}
                  name={name}
                  {...{
                    isActive: id === active.id,
                    setActive: () => setActive(details)
                  }}
                />
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <RightSection
          name={active.name}
          apps={active.tiles}
          {...{ json, setJson }}
        />
      </div>
      <p>{JSON.stringify(json, null, 2)}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: because your `onChange` handling logic is wrong

Comment: You could see the state being changed

Comment: not your handle is wrong i will correct on your codesandbox ok?

Answer (score 0):

since you have not updated data of checkbox (in your code) / logic is wrong (in codesandbox) do the following add this function in `RightSection`

```js
...
  function setTick(app, value: boolean) {
    app.checked = value;
    setJson({...json})
  }
...
```

and `onChange` in input checkbox

```
              <input
                onChange={({ target }) => setTick(app, target.checked)}
                checked={app.checked}
                type="checkbox"
              />
```

Codesandbox: see `line 25 -> 28` and `line 48` in `RightSection.tsx` are the lines I added

For the two buttons `select all` and `unselect all` to update the state of the checkboxes, the data must be synchronized (here you declare `active` as `json` independent of each other, this makes the update logic complicated. Unnecessarily complicated, please fix it to sync

```
  const [json, setJson] = useState(dummyJson);
  const [activeId, setActiveId] = useState('cat1');
  const active = useMemo(() => json[activeId], [json, activeId]);
```

and update depends:

```
                <SidebarItem
                  key={name}
                  name={name}
                  {...{
                    isActive: id === activeId,
                    setActive: () => setActiveId(id)
                  }}
                />
```

Codesandbox: `line 60 -> 63` and `line 81 -> 82` in file `App.js`

https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-rhodes-yp40fi

> the `handleOperation` function could also be rewritten very succinctly but that is beyond the scope of the question

Comment: please let me know when you have finished looking at the codesandbox as i need to delete it

Comment: I wanted the select all and unselect all logic to get worked.

Comment: you want to add 2 buttons that work why you need them to react. I will correct my answer

Comment: its already added. And the state is getting updated as well. Only checkboxes are not taking the change. Not sure why

Comment: i updated the answer and added an explanation read it

Comment: thanks.what does     setJson({...json}) do?

Comment: it updates `json` with a cloned object more in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax
use it after you edit the json by assigning `json[<prop name>] = ...` you can use it to minify the code like i mentioned